# Adding Multiarch for kubuntu 14.4

Tags: multiarch

I have this kind of system:

```
:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

When I try to

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the error messages

```
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.204 80]
```

What can I do to add the armhf stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `armhf` port is hosted on the ports archive, not the main archive. To allow `apt` to find the relevant indexes and packages, you need to:

- qualify your existing entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `[arch=amd64]`, for example

  ```
  deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
  ```
- add entries for `armhf`, for example

  ```
  deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty main restricted universe multiverse
  ```

(repeating as necessary for the various 14.04 repositories).

Once you’ve done that, `apt-get update` should work fine and you should be able to install `armhf` libraries.

Comment: I added the line `deb [arch=armhf] http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync non-free`. Do you mean that I simply should add `[arch=amd64]` to every other `deb` (before that new deb I have not been using any a`armhf` or anything like it)?

Comment: Yes, otherwise `apt` reckons it should look for `armhf` indexes there too.